# Knockoutjs add multiple click events to radiobutton

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

How do I add multiple click events to radiobutton in knockoutjs?

I have this right now,

```
AddDataBind="click: myObject.Event, clickBubble: true"
```

and I tried

```
AddDataBind="click: myObject.Event,Event2, clickBubble: true"
```

and

```
AddDataBind="click: myObject.Event+Event2, clickBubble: true"
```

both are not working.

Comment: Try using `AddDataBind="click: function() { myObject.Event; Event2; }, clickBubble: true"`, or create a function that handle both `myObject.Event` and `Event2` then point that function to click event.

Answer (score 0):

i do not know `AddDataBind` syntax but in pure javascript you are able to do this

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="
  click:function(data, event){
    myObject.Event(data, event);
    myObject.Event2(data, event);
  },
  clickBubble: true
">
```

but questions is why you need it? probably your view model is not well designed. can you share more of your code and your intentions?